# Left Join Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of Vendors (Vendors):

```
+-----+-------------+--+
| ID  |   Vendor    |  |
+-----+-------------+--+
|   1 | ABC Company |  |
|   2 | DEF Company |  |
|   3 | GHI Company |  |
| ... | ...         |  |
+-----+-------------+--+
```

and a table of services (AllServices):

```
+-----+------------+--+
| ID  |  Service   |  |
+-----+------------+--+
|   1 | Automotive |  |
|   2 | Medical    |  |
|   3 | Financial  |  |
| ... | ...        |  |
+-----+------------+--+
```

and a table that links the two (VendorServices):

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Vendor ID | ServiceID |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         1 |
|         1 |         3 |
|         3 |         2 |
|       ... |       ... |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Note that one company may provide multiple services while some companies may not provide any of the listed services.

The query results I want would be, for a given Vendor:

```
+------------+----------+
| Service ID | Provided |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        0 |
|          2 |        0 |
|          3 |        1 |
|        ... |      ... |
+------------+----------+
```

Where ALL of the services are listed and the ones that the given vendor provides would have a 1 in the Provided column, otherwise a zero.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT
    VendorServices.ServiceID,
    <Some Function> AS Provided 
FROM
    AllServices LEFT JOIN VendorServices ON AllServices.ID = VendorServices.ServiceID
WHERE
    VendorServices.VendorID = @VendorID
ORDER BY
    Service
```

I have two unknowns:

1. The above query does not return every entry in the AllServices table; and
2. I don't know how to write the function for the Preovided column.

Comment: Doing a `LEFT JOIN` to a table, and then referencing that table in the `WHERE`  *without* catering for `NULL` values implicitly converts the `JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. I suspect the clause in the `WHERE` should be in the `ON`. Otherwise you need to handle `NULL` values, as *nothing` equals `NULL`, including `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a LEFT join of `AllServices` to `VendorServices` and a `case` expression to get the column `provided`:

```
select s.id,
       case when v.serviceid is null then 0 else 1 end provided
from AllServices s left join VendorServices v
on v.serviceid = s.id and v.vendorid = @VendorID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48efc1dcbdc0856cee4651604b5d2a28).

Comment: That works but I'm a bit of a novice on SQL so please explain what this part v.vendorid = @VendorID is part of the JOIN condition and not in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @SezMe if the condition `v.vendorid = @VendorID` was in the WHERE clause then all the non matching rows of AllServices would be filtered out, because only non null vendorids would be returned, so this join would actually be an INNER join. By putting the condition in the ON clause the result is all the rows of  AllServices.